# How do I stream edit progress-like output?

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, perl, string

I'm having trouble editing some progress output.  In this case it's Postgres' `pg_basebackup`, but it's similar to other progress output like curl and wget.  Take for example the output of this:

```
generate_output() {
    for f in {1..500}; do 
        sleep 0.01
        echo -ne "Downloading... $f/500 foo   \\r"
    done
    echo -e "\nSome final line 1\nSome final line 2"
}
```

Which has output like this

```
Downloading... 1/500 foo
(...same line...)
Downloading... 500/500 foo
Some final line 1
Some final line 2
```

**How could I remove the "foo" from this output while keeping the progress-like nature?** (instead of it being buffered, and therefore useless)

I've tried both `awk` and `sed` but both seem to heavily rely on line buffering, and there's no newline in the `Downloading...` output until it's completely finished.

The closest I've gotten is a hack which first replaces `CR` with `LF`, then replaces it again after.  But this screws up the actual newlines (e.g. "Some final line 1")

```
generate_output | stdbuf -i0 -o0 tr $'\r' $'\n' | sed -u -e 's/ foo//' | stdbuf -i0 -o0 tr $'\n' $'\r'
```

Is there a way to configure `awk` or `sed` to handle this?  Or a better tool for the job?

Notes:

- The above output was sanitized for generality.  Actual output is `42318/42318 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace`, and I would like to trim everything including and after the comma.
- I've seen some suggestions surrounding the awk -W interactive option, which is not available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a **perl** one-liner to pipe your generate_output into:

```
perl -e '$/ = "\r"; $| = 1; while(<STDIN>){s/ foo//;print;}'
```

`$/` sets the input line delimiter, and `$|` makes output unbuffered.

Comment: I tried these both out and they both worked great!  Thanks so much for your help.  I ended up going for the perl solution because (I think) it extends to a complex regex easier than the other one (though I'm not too familiar with the `{line% foo}` syntax, I believe it's not a pattern).

Comment: You are right, whereas the perl `s///` takes a regexp, the bash `${%}` needs a glob pattern, i.e. you can use filename matching style `*`  `?` and `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **bash** solution to pipe your `generate_output` into:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -d $'\r' line
do      echo -ne "${line% foo}\r"
done
echo "$line"
```